# Select first Descendant with CSS

Tags: css, html

Is there anyway to select *only* the first descendant using CSS. For example, is there anyway to start at the .container element and style the <li class="example"> with a blue border, but not the <p class="example"> within it?

I know there are a ton of alternative ways to to this in CSS.  But is there a way to do it with the exact code below?  Meaning use only the selector classes .container and .example, leave the class .container exactly where it is within the HTML below, and use the exact HTML markup below.

```
<style>
    .container .example{
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="example"><p class="example"></p></li>
            <li class="example"><p class="example"></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will select both the `li`s and the `p`s, as they are both first children of their parents.

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect what you have said in comments. As asked now, the question is very vague. “The first descendant”... of what? Why do you write about “the exact HTML markup below” when you comment “this is just an example”? Example of what? In your markup, the first descendant of `<div class="container">` is the `ul` element, so are you asking how to select it, or what? What is the practical need behind all this?

Answer (score 24):

Do you mean the "direct child selector"?

```
.container > ul > li
```

..here it is your blue border:

```
.container > ul > li {
    border: solid 1px #00f;
}
```

..to only use classes, you can accomplish that with something like:

```
.container > * > .example{
    border: solid 1px #00f;
}
```

### Select "first in hierarchy"

css2 way (and still the more robust, I think) was to add border to `.example` and remove from `.example .example`:

```
.example{
    border: solid 1px #00f;
}
.example .example{
    border: none;
}
```

In CSS3, you can do this:

```
:not(.example) > .example{
    border: solid 1px #00f;
}
```

just beware that this will *not* prevent `.example > div > .example` from getting the blue border too..
but it guarantees no `.example` that is direct child of another `.example` will get that style.

### update: start with .container

what about `.container :not(.example) > .example`?

I don't thing you can do better with "clean" css (ie. single rule; without resetting etc.).

The meaning of `not()` selector is  "match any item that doesn't match the selector", not "forbid this selector to match somewhere here in the rule"..

Comment: No. Is there a solution that would do something like .container ( magicial css here ) .example{ border: 1px solid blue }

Comment: if you replace ``( magic css here )`` with ``> * >``, you get exactly what you asked for..

Comment: I like that wildcard, but it's not exactly true he'll get what he asked for. If there's another wrapper besides the `ul` between `.container` and `li.example`, it will break.

Comment: oh, so you want to select only the first of hierarchy?

Comment: Not quite there. The selector, must start with .container.

Comment: That's not exactly it, but like ya said, that might be the best we can do.

Answer (score 7):

First immediate child:

```
.container ul > :first-child{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sprynm/pen/PpKBRe

The `<ul>` adds a bit of complexity since there is a node between the `.container` and target.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
li.example:first-child {border: 1px solid blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that exact markup, why are you restricted to only `.container` and `.example` classes in selectors?

`.container ul > li.example` would select what you want, although it doesn't fit your class restriction.

(`>` is the child selector)

Another alternative which does fit all your restrictions is this:

```
.container .example {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container .example .example {
 border: none; 
}
```

its limitation is that it obviously doesn't select only the first descendant; it simply overrides the style on all non-first-descendants.

Comment: B/c this is just an example.  I'm trying to come up with ways make the BEM css idealogy a little better.

Comment: how does my second suggestion suit you?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's not what I'm asking for.  Please see the comments in the first answer.

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about the number of wrapping layers between `.container` and the first descendant `.example`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
.container ul li{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```