# CSS select first-of-type amongst grandchildren?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've read tricky questions such as [Select first Descendant with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922841/select-first-descendant-with-css) or [How do I hide only the first element of a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772494/how-do-i-hide-only-the-first-element-of-a-type) but mine doesn't match these ones.

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>
        <p class="interline"><!-- only this -->
        <p class="interline">
        <p class="interline">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="interline">
        <p class="interline">
        <p class="interline">
    </div>
</div>
```

And want to select only the first grandchild `<p>` under the .parent div.

How do I do that?

Comment: Does it have to be a generic solution to what you're asking (first arbitrary grandchild of any arbitrary element) or just for your code? For that you can use `p.interline:first-child`.

Comment: I tried `p.interline:first-child` and it didn't worked because, as shown in the answers below, I should have though of selecting the first `<div>` too, which I haven't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to select the first `div` as well

```
.parent > div:first-of-type > p:first-of-type {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eHeJ/)</kbd>

Here in the above selector, I am selecting the first `p` element nested inside the first `div`, which is further nested as *direct* child to an element having a `class` of `.parent`

`>` means select direct descendant to it's parent.

---

The above will fail in older versions of Internet Explorer, so if you are looking to support them as well, than equivalent supported selector will be

```
.parent > div:first-child > p:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4eHeJ/2/)</kbd> *(Supports IE7 as well)*

But using [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) has huge difference, say you are using `p:first-child` and you have some other element apart from `p`, your selector will fail, so that's why I provided you a solution of using `:first-of-type`

Answer (score 3):

```
.parent > div:first-child > p:first-child
```

Here you go, this should work for you

Answer (score 0):

It would be `.parent p.interline:first-child` or `.parent .interline:first-child`.

Comment: Hi @shecodes, welcome to the site! This looks like a good start of an answer. Can you add more description of *why* this answer is correct?

Comment: As said above, didn't work because the first `p`-child of every `div` is selected.

Comment: Hi @Kazark, thanks for the welcome! @maxxyme you could use `.parent div:first-child .interline:first-child {color: red;}` or the answer selected above :)