# how to select the 2nd child Div of a div using CSS

Tags: wordpress, css, css-selectors, padding

I am trying to style a div in wordpress. As you cant give anything IDs I have to select to using CSS3 `:nth-child()` Selector. I am trying to target the third div
My css rules I am trying but it not working any ideas where I am going wrong

```
#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap:nth-of-type(2) {
    padding: 0px;
}


<div id="ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap" >
    <div class="ninja-row">
         <div class="ninja-col-1-2">
```

Comment: So you're trying to style "ninja-col-1-2"?

Comment: Yes and that's is a sibling of the second div but I cant edit the class its given because the its needed else where

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS select first-of-type amongst grandchildren?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461894/css-select-first-of-type-amongst-grandchildren)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:         `#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap>div:first-of- type>div: first-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this :

1. First wrap your three divs into a div
2. Then select the second one

```css
.all-ninja div:nth-child(2) {
  //Write your CSS
}
```

```html
<div class="all-ninja">
    <div id="ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap" >
    <div class="ninja-row">
    <div class="ninja-col-1-2">
</div>
```

Comment: Its wordpress plugin that builds a form I cant edit the HTML

Answer (score 0):

**If i m not wrong your markup should be something like this:**

```
<div id="ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap" >
      <div class="ninja-row">
           <div class="ninja-col-1-2">
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

so you need to use direct class to style `.ninaj-col-1-2` instead of using `:nth-child`

**Below code should work**

```
#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap .ninja-col-1-2{
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Will this not effect all divs? I just to select that div

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting that using `div`.

```css
#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:#ccc;
}
#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap > .ninja-row{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #f22;
}
#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap > .ninja-row > .ninja-col-1-2{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}

#ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap > .ninja-row div:nth-child(1){
  background:#111;
}
```

```html
<div id="ninja_forms_form_175_all_fields_wrap" >
<div class="ninja-row">
<div class="ninja-col-1-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```