# CSS Selector for all descendants excluding nested instances

Tags: css

I have a question related to [Select first Descendant with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922841/select-first-descendant-with-css) or [How do I hide only the first element of a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772494/how-do-i-hide-only-the-first-element-of-a-type) but my case doesn't match these ones.

I need to target all `.page` descendants of class `.example` but **excluding** nested `.example`.

In this example, I'd like to target only `#h1-a` and `#h1-c`:

```
<div class="page">
  <!-- there could be many levels of wrapping -->
  <div>
    <div>
      <div id="h1-a" class="example">
        <h1>h1-a</h1>
        <div>
          <div id="h1-b" class="example">
            <h1>h1-b (nested)</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- or there could be none -->
  <div id="h1-c" class="example">
    <h1>h1-c</h1>
    <div>
      <div id="h1-d" class="example">
        <h1>h1-d (nested)</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dae1obq2/2/) to get us started.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible. The closest you can get with pure CSS would involve selecting all descendants, then overriding the styling for nested descendants - https://jsfiddle.net/4tqczcLt/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS cascade to overwrite an earlier rule (applying to a more general context) with a later rule (applying to a more specific context):

```
.page .example {
border: 1px solid rgb(127,127,127);
}

.page .example .example {
border: none;
}
```

This is exactly how the CSS cascade is supposed to work - general rules higher up, specific exceptions lower down.