# select first decendant with class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't have control of the html structure, so for example if I have this structure:

```
<body>
 <div class="red"> <------ style this
    <div>content</div>
    <div class="red">
     <div>
      <div class="red">content</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to style only the first decendant with the red class..

```css
:not(.red) > * > .red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
    <div>red</div>
    <div class="red">
     <div>
      <div class="red">red</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have tried following this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12922863/2894798  with no results if you inspect the dom in my example you will see that the second decendant with the red class, also has the red style..
Do note that I am trying to select first decendant not first sibling

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want. You said, _"I want to style only the first decendant with the red class.."_ but in your HTML example you have `<------ style this` pointed to a div with the red class as a descendant of nothing, except ostensibly the body, but with multiple descendants also containing the red class

Comment: I have updated the example as I said I don't have control of the dom, so the structure can change, to be more clear I want the first decendant in the dom tree

Comment: the answer you accepted exists in the link you shared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you target all elements that have the `.red` class. Then you unset it from all childs having also this class.

```
.red {
  background: red;
}

.red  .red {
  background: none;
}
```

Comment: This  will work for a siblings level I am trying to select it on the html structure

Comment: Check my updated approach

Comment: This will work as a workaround, you will have to overwrite the used properties, if I don't get other anwers I will mark this as the correct one...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` CSS selector to target only first element without overwriting any properties.

```
body > .red { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```css
div { padding: 5px; }
body > .red { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="red"> style this
    <div>content</div>
    <div class="red">
       <div>
          <div class="red">content</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: will work only If the .red is children of the body... i don't have control of the html so teh structure might change